# Proper usage of the theorems of Fubini and Tonelli

Tags: measure-theory, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I've just learned about the (rigorous versions of the) theorems of Fubini and Tonelli, given below.

> **Theorem:** (Fubini) Suppose $\left(X,\mathcal{A},\mu\right)$ and $\left(Y,\mathcal{B},\nu\right)$ are $\sigma$-finite measure spaces, and suppose that $X\times Y$ is given the product measure $\mu\times\nu$. If $f$ is $X\times Y$ integrable, meaning that $f$ is a measurable function and
> $$\int_{X\times Y}|f(x,y)|\,d(\mu\times\nu)<\infty,$$
> then
> $$\int_{X\times Y}f(x,y)\,d(\mu\times\nu) = \int_{X}\left(\int_Y f(x,y) \, d\nu\right) \, d\mu = \int_Y\left(\int_X f(x,y) \, d\mu\right) \, d\nu.$$

> **Theorem:** (Tonelli) Suppose $\left(X,\mathcal{A},\mu\right)$ and $\left(Y,\mathcal{B},\nu\right)$ are $\sigma$-finite measure spaces, and suppose that $X\times Y$ is given the product measure $\mu\times\nu$. If $f$ is a measurable function and non-negative then
> $$\int_{X\times Y}f(x,y) \, d(\mu\times\nu) = \int_X \left(\int_Y f(x,y) \, d\nu\right) \, d\mu = \int_Y \left(\int_X f(x,y) \, d\mu\right) \, d\nu.$$

Lets say I wanted to employ these theorems to solve the following integral, given below.

> **Problem:** For $0<a<b$ consider
> $$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-ax}-e^{-bx}}{x} \, dx.$$

I know how to solve the problem, but I'm interested more on how to actually be completely rigorous when employing these theorems. More specifically, I have the following question: To solve the problem, we write

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-ax}-e^{-bx}}{x} \, dx = \int_0^\infty \int_a^b e^{-yx} \, dy \, dx \overbrace{=}^{(1)} \int_a^b \int_0^\infty e^{-yx} \, dx \, dy.$$

How do I use the theorems of Fubini or Tonelli to justify $(1)$? Should I say since $[a,b]$ and $[0,\infty)$ are $\sigma$-finite and $f(x,y):=e^{-yx}$ is a non-negative measurable function, we have by Tonellis theorem $(1)$ holds?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly right.

Comment: @PeterMorfe: Thanks for the conformation :-)

Comment: @D.Math : Peter Morfe did not _conform_ something; rather he _confirmed_ something.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Whoops, typo!